# How to embed AsciiMathML in Google Sites?

Tags: javascript, math, mathml, google-sites

We would need to embed mathematical formulas through [AsciiMathML](http://www1.chapman.edu/~jipsen/asciimath.html) into [Google Sites](http://sites.google.com) pages (internal wiki for a research team). I am stuck with the limitation of Google Sites.

Any idea how to do that?

(ps: I have finally found a [poorly practical work-around](http://blog.vermorel.com/?p=91), but better ideas would still be appreciated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to use [texify.com](http://www.texify.com/), but they're no longer available.  Now I use [Google Infographics Mathematical Formulas](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/infographics/docs/formulas.html), which has more features *and* (IMO) is more likely to continue being available in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out that Google now support TeX. That's very handy.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but found texify: http://www.texify.com/ as a complete solution. Texify is an online tex editor rendering gifs, and not AsciiMathML, but I found it quick to get the hang of. Just add the html code generated into your source in Google Sites, or insert picture from the GUI.

Comment: Texify is nice, but I would be worried to have to really use it for anything professional. They do not seems to have any business model; thus, the service is likely to disappear the day the webmaster get tired of it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how if this is an acceptable solution for you, but you can upload your own HTML (or any other type for that matter) files on Google Pages. So the proposes solution would be: write manually the HTML pages with the necessary JS tags and upload them to Google Pages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use manually edited HTML for this purpose. Google-sites strips off all "embed" statements in HTML. One solution is to build a google gadget with your AsciiMathML and then insert the gadget into the site. A smart solution would be to search for existing google gadget that servers your purpose ;-) Good luck!